# Why I can't use "If Sheets('worksheetname') Is Nothing" to check if a worksheet exists in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I mean, I know how to use On Error Resume Next to solve this problem. But I just don't understand why this error will happen. Why excel compiler won't return Nothing if it can't find certain worksheet.... Do I misunderstand some concept?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that will error out if `Sheets("Output")` is not really existing.
You are trying to access an object that does not exist.

Try this:

```
Dim wsop As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set wsop = Sheets("Output")
On Error Goto 0

If wsop Is Nothing Then
    Set wsop = Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)) 'after last sheet
    wsop.Name = "Output"
End If
```

Take note that we use *OERN* and *OEG0* to suppress error during variable assignment. 
To know more about [error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm) check out the link. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub test()

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set wsSheet = Sheets("Output") 'declare before check
On Error GoTo 0
If wsSheet Is Nothing Then
 Worksheets.Add.Name = "Output"
End If

End Sub
```